# Document an application server

Tags: documentation, webserver, document

Does anyone have a Server Documentation Template they would be willing to share? I used to work on an application server (Linux) for a while and now I have to document everything in order to deliver all my work to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Sydi.. that will document the server for you with scripts